# Show that if $z = e^{i\theta}$ is a solution to $0 = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0$, ...

Tags: complex-numbers, problem-solving

Show that if $z = e^{i\theta}$ is a solution to $0 = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0$ **[1]** where all $a_i$ are real, then $0 = a_{n-1}\sin\theta + a_{n-2}\sin2\theta + \cdots + a_0 \sin n\theta$ **[2]**

So far I have realized that [2] states that the complex polynomial $a_0z^n +a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots a_{n-1}z$ [3] is real. I am trying to convert [1] to [3] but have not had any luck so far. I've tried some other stuff as well; can anyone solve the problem?

Thank you so much everyone for your solutions! I woke up this morning and in a flash of inspiration figured out the solution. Looks like my proof agrees with yours'.

Comment: Take real parts.

Comment: @mixedmath Okay, I just tried that. I broke it down into cosine and sine equations and spent a while doing manipulations on them, but I haven't made any progress. Sorry if this is a trivial question but I'm new to complex numbers and haven't really wrapped my mind around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since
$$
0= e^{in\theta}+ a_{n-1}e^{i(n-1)\theta}+\cdots + a_0
$$
Then, dividing by $e^{in\theta}$ we get
$$
0=1+a_{n-1}e^{-i\theta}+\cdots +a_0e^{-in\theta}
$$
Since $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ for every real $x$, then after grouping some terms we have
$$
0=(1+a_{n-1}\cos(-\theta)+\cdots +a_0\cos(-n\theta))+i(a_{n-1}\sin(-\theta)+\cdots +a_0\sin(-n\theta))
$$
Since all of the $a_k$ are real, this expression is in the form $a+ib$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and since it is equal to zero, we should have $b=0$, that is,
$$
0=a_{n-1}\sin(-\theta)+\cdots +a_0\sin(-n\theta))
$$
And using that $\sin$ is an odd function, we have the result.

Answer (score 1):

For notational convenience, set $a_n = 1$.  Then the given equation may be written

$\sum_{m = 0}^n a_m z^m = 0; \tag{1}$

next, recall that $(\cos m \theta + i\sin m \theta) = e^{i m \theta} = (e^{i \theta})^m$ by de Moivre's formula.  Inserting $z = e^{i \theta}$ into (1), it becomes

$\sum_{m = 0}^n a_m e^{i m \theta} =0, \tag{2}$

so that now if we multiply through by $e^{-i n \theta}$ we obtain

$\sum_{m = 0}^n a_m e^{i (m - n) \theta} = 0, \tag{3}$

or

$\sum_{m = 0}^n a_m (\cos (m - n) \theta + i\sin (m- n) \theta) = 0. \tag{4}$

Notice that the $m = n$ term in (4) is $1$; as for the rest, taking the imaginary part yields

$\sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1} a_m \sin (n - m) \theta = 0, \tag{5}$

where the fact that $\sin(- \alpha) = -\sin \alpha$ has been used in the transition 'twixt (4) and (5).  It is easy to see that (5) is the requisite sum.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***